# How can I enable Wi-Fi calling only when I'm at home?

Tags: wi-fi, settings, automation

I have a phone running Android Nougat. I live in location with poor cell service, so I'd like to use Wi-Fi calling at home. But I want to use cell service for phone calls everywhere else, especially when I'm at work or connected to a public hotspot with questionable bandwidth. Is there a way to automate this?

In the Wi-Fi calling settings, I can tell the phone to prefer Wi-Fi or cellular, but it always uses the preferred service if it's available, even if the quality is terrible. So I'm hoping for a solution that automatically enables or disables Wi-Fi calling based on location or network name.

Answer (score 0):

[This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=de) does more or less exactly what you want.

You can create rules for entering and leaving an area. You could, for example, if you are at home simply switch off mobile data and connect Wlan.You can also connect the rule with your reception quality, try what works best.

Comment: Llama looks like a great app for a lot of things, but not the best choice for this case.  It can turn Wi-Fi on and off, but I want to leave Wi-Fi on all the time.  The only setting I want to change is Wi-Fi calling.